# I cannot publish a sample app via Ingress.: failed to call webhook

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, cicd, argocd

※I am a beginner, so if you have any information you need, please comment.

Based on the  [yaml file](https://gitlab.com/cloudnative_impress/bookinfo-manifests/-/blob/main/deploy/overlays/stg/bookinfo-ingress.yaml), I am trying to publish a sample app that has already been launched in Pod via Ingress.

`$kubectl apply -f ./overlays/stg/bookinfo-ingress.yaml`
■Errormessage

```
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "./overlays/stg/bookinfo-ingress.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/networking/v1/ingresses?timeout=10s": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```